# Sort and remove duplicates line by line in text file

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, duplicates

So I have this text file that I wanted to sort. The contents of the text file looks something like this:
***I used "\r\n" at the end of each line when I was writing them in***

Gere is the code that I used writing this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$fileName = "GuestBook.txt";

  $fh = fopen($fileName, "a");
    fwrite($fh, $name);
    fwrite($fh, "----");
    fwrite($fh, $email . "\r\n");
  fclose($fh);
```

Opening txt file on the notepad it looks something like this:

```
aaa----aaa
ggg----ggg
sss----sss
www----www
ttt----ttt
ppp----ppp
ggg----ggg
zzz----zzz
www----www
```

Now I want it to display it sorted with duplicates removed:

```
aaa----aaa
ggg----ggg
ppp----ppp
sss----sss
ttt----ttt
www----www
zzz----zzz
```

This is what I did for sorting them:

```
$fileName = "GuestBook.txt";

$data = file_get_contents($fileName);
$split = explode("\n",$data);

sort($split);

$data = implode("\n",$split);

file_put_contents($fileName, $data);
```

This is what I have for removing duplicates

```
$fileName = "GuestBook.txt";

$lines = file($fileName);
$lines = array_unique($lines);

file_put_contents($fileName, implode("\n",$lines));
```

Comment: yep i did, i can put my sort and remove duplicate code...

Comment: That would be capital!

Comment: those are inside functions sort_book() and remove_dups() 
i have a button that when i click,
i call those function and another code that reads the function

Comment: just as an aside, according to PHP docs, array_unique sorts the resulting array as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the output sorted and unique from the file you can do something like this:

First reading the file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), so you have each line as one array element. Then you can use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) so you only have unique lines/elements.

After that you can sort the array with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and apply [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) as callback.

Code:

```
<?php

    $fileName = "GuestBook.txt";
    $lines = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = array_unique($lines);

    usort($lines, "strcasecmp");

    print_r($lines);

?>
```

---

If you want to store them already unique you can do it like this:

Also read the file into an array with `file()` and just check with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if you already have the value in your array. If not add the value to the file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fileName = "GuestBook.txt";

    $lines = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    if(!in_array($name . "----" . $email, $lines)){
        file_put_contents($fileName, $name . "----" . $email . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }

?>
```

And if you want to add the value already sorted into the file you can do it like this:

Again get your file into an array, add the value to the array, sort it and you can put it back again.

Code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fileName = "GuestBook.txt";

    $lines = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines[] = $name . "----" . $email;

    usort($lines, "strcasecmp");

    file_put_contents($fileName, implode("\r\n", $lines), FILE_APPEND);


?>
```

And of course if you want them already unique and sorted just combine the two code snippets from above.

Comment: Can i just use file_put_contents($fileName, $lines) to put back to my txt file? thank you

Comment: @javaMan1995 Depends, If you have all your data in `$lines` and they have a new line at the end of each value you can put it back like this: `file_put_contents($fileName, $lines)`. If they need the new line again, just `implode()` them before putting it back: `file_put_contents($fileName, implode("\r\n", $lines)`. And if you just want to append one value to the file, you have to set the flag, e.g. `file_put_contents($fileName, $name . "----" . $email . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND)`

Answer (score 1):

Load the file into an array, remove duplicates and then sort:

```
$lines = array_unique(file('/path/to/file.txt'));
sort($lines);
```

Depending on file structure you may use one or both of `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`.

Then to save, if you don't use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` (if so you have to add them):

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $lines);
```

Comment: it worked. thanks so much! however, is there a way to put those inside the original text file? like can i use file_put_contents($fileName, $lines) to put back to my txt file? thank you

Comment: Yes, what you have should work and if not then make sure error reporting is on you may have a permission issue or something.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
$lines = array();
while ( $line = fgets($fh) ) {
  $lines[] = $line;
}
$arr = array_unique($lines);
foreach ( $arr as $line ) {
  echo $line . "\r\n";
}
```